# search returning subfolder not main folder in bash

Tags: bash

I have the below `bash` that searches a specific directory and returns the earliest folder in that directory.  The `bash` works great if their are no subfolders within each folder.  If there is those are returned instead of the main folder.  I am not sure why this is happening or how to fix it.  Thank you :).

For example,

`/home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/test` is the directory searched and in it there are two folder, `R_1 and R_2`

**output**

```
 The earliest folder is: R_1
```

However, if /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/test`has`R_1 and within it testfolder`and`R_2 and testfolder2 within it`

**output**

```
The earliest folder is: testfolder
```

**Bash**

```
cd /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/test
folder=$(ls -u *"R_"* | head -n 1) # earliest folder
echo "The earliest folder is: $folder"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ls` is the wrong tool for this job: Its output is built for humans, not scripts, and is often surprising when nonprintable characters are present.

---

Assuming you have GNU `find` and `sort`, the following works with all possible filenames, including those with literal newlines:

```
dir=/home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/test # for my testing, it's "."
{
  read -r -d $'\t' time && read -r -d '' filename
} < <(find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -printf '%T+\t%P\0' | sort -z -r )
```

...thereafter:

```
echo "The oldest file is $filename, with an mtime of $time"
```

---

For a larger discussion of portably finding the newest or oldest file in a directory, including options that *don't* require GNU tools, see [BashFAQ #99](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/099).

Comment: Thank you both very much for your help and explanations :).

Answer (score 1):

You should read about ls, the -u option doesn't do what you think it does. The following are the relevant options:

- -u - Tells ls to use last access time instead of last modification time when sorting by time. So by itself it does nothing, should be called with -t
- -t - Sorts by time (of modification or access or something else), with newest first
- -r - Reverses order of output
- -d - Don't search directories recursively

So what you actually need is:

```
$ ls -trd
```

Or:

```
$ ls -utrd
```